# splinter select(value) returns Attribute error

Tags: python, select, splinter

Trying to get all the (5) tables from this url.

http://www.molpower.com//VLCWeb/UIAboutMOL/PortScheduleInfo.aspx?pPort=NLRTMDE&pFromDate=01-Oct-2013&pToDate=10-Oct-2013

The drop box for the individual pages I can populate with `type(value)` but this does not refresh the page. Stepping through the pages with the nextPage button fails after one because the object is not longer attached to the DOM (and I don't know how to get around that in splinter).

Trying to populate the drop down and then selecting it. This returns this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 69, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 334, in select
 self.find_by_xpath('//select[@name="%s"]/option[@value="%s"]' % (self["name"], value))._element.click()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 73, in __getattr__
  self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute '_element'
```

I used the code below. Any help most appreciated!

```
from splinter import Browser
from lxml.html import parse
from StringIO import StringIO
from time import sleep

url = r'http://www.molpower.com//VLCWeb/UIAboutMOL/PortScheduleInfo.aspx?pPort=NLRTMDE&pFromDate=01-Oct-2013&pToDate=10-Oct-2013'

def _unpack(row, kind = 'td'):
    elts = row.findall('.//%s' %kind)
    return [val.text_content() for val in elts[0:7]]

def parse_schdls_data(table):
    rows = table.findall('.//tr')
    hdrs = _unpack(rows[0], kind = 'th')
    data = [_unpack(r, kind = 'td') for ir, r in enumerate(rows[1:-1]) if ir % 3 == 0]
    return (hdrs, data)

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.visit(url)
    print browser.url

    pages = browser.find_by_tag('option')

    pagevals = [p.value for p in pages]
    maxpagev = max(pagevals)

    inputs = browser.find_by_tag('input')

    '''
    for ip, inp in enumerate(inputs):
        if inp.has_class('btnMRBPageNext'):
            #print ip, inp.value, inp.text
            #Need input 35 for the nextPage 
            inp.click()
    '''

    selects = browser.find_by_tag('select')

    for ns, sel in enumerate(selects):
        if sel.has_class('inputDropDown'):
            print ns, sel.value, sel.text
            sel.type(sel.value)
            sleep(2)

    moldata = list()
    for page in range(len(pagevals)):

        content = browser.html
        parsed = parse(StringIO(content))
        doc = parsed.getroot()
        tables = doc.findall('.//table')
        schdls = tables[91]

        #Get all rows from that table
        rows = schdls.findall('.//tr')
        hdr, data = parse_schdls_data(schdls)
        #print page, data
        moldata.append(data)

        while browser.is_element_not_present_by_tag('select', wait_time = 2):
            pass

        inputs = browser.find_by_tag('input')
        selects = browser.find_by_tag('select')

        #inputs[35].click()

        #selects[0].type(str(page + 1))
        selects[0].select(selects[0].value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the select element do not have a name, so for example:

```
browser.find_by_xpath('//select[@id="MRBgvPortScheduleInformation_edlPager"]/option[@value="2"]')._element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you got the reference to the select elements by calling

```
selects = browser.find_by_tag('select')
```

and then call the select method on this elements

```
selects[0].select(selects[0].value)
```

But from the traceback we can know, the splinter converts it to find_by_xpath

```
self.find_by_xpath('//select[@name="%s"]/option[@value="%s"]' % (self["name"], value))._element.click()
```

Where it assumes the `select` element has a name, if there is no name for the select, there will be an error.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id='s1'>
<option value='a'> A </option>
<option value='b'> B </option>
<option value='c'> C </option>
</select>

<select id='s2'>
<option value='a'> A </option>
<option value='b'> B </option>
<option value='c'> C </option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

We can reproduce this error with previous HTML page, and after we add names to the 2 `select` elements, errors gone.